# When overriding default configuration for Date Serialization, it becomes missing in the JSON example in metadata pages

Tags: servicestack

I am attempting to override the default DateTime serialization with the following code:

```
JsConfig<DateTime>.SerializeFn = d =>
        {
            return d.ToString("o") + "Z";
        };
JsConfig<DateTime>.RawSerializeFn = d =>
        {
            return d.ToString("o") + "Z";
        };
```

(not sure the diff between SerializeFn and RawSerializeFn so i tried both to be sure...I also tried implementing the DeserializeFn in case they both needed to be overwritten, but saw some results)

Anyways... everytime I try this, any date members in our DTOs goes missing in the sample request/response JSON on the metadata pages. (date members still show in the Parameters section though).

I am using SS v4.0.40.0

PS: I later realized that my whole goal of appending "Z" to all DateTimes could be accomplished with this configuration:

```
        JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601;
        JsConfig.AssumeUtc = true;
        JsConfig.AppendUtcOffset = false;
```

but I still wanted to file this bug - Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DateTime` serialization can't be changed in isolation, if you take over serializing to an unsupported custom format you'll also need to handle deserializing it with the appropriate `RawDeserializeFn/DeserializeFn` configuration.

You can also handle parsing unknown `DateTime` formats by registering a ParseError callback, i.e:

```
DateTimeSerializer.OnParseErrorFn = (dateTimeStr, ex) => //DateTime;
```

If you want to file an issue with any ServiceStack libraries, upgrade to the latest version of ServiceStack to ensure it's still an issue, if it is please submit it to [github.com/ServiceStack/Issues](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues) with a sample code/failing test that reproduces the issue.